# COBOL line sequential write carriage return not automatic

Tags: file, cobol

Hello and thanks in advance for the help. I am a tutor with limited experience with COBOL. I have generalized the variable names as to not publish an answer to a school assignment.

The output of the file as is shown here

[image: proper output accomplished with hack]

is perfect, but without this hack line

```
05 FILLER PIC X VALUE X'0d'.
```

at the end of each group to be written to the file, there will not be any carriage returns and so all of the data shows up on one line.

My students and I would really appreciate any additional helpful comments or resources you would like to provide as well.

Thanks again.

```
   environment division.
       INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.
       FILE-CONTROL.
       SELECT FILE-IN
       ASSIGN TO 'IN.DAT'
       ORGANIZATION IS LINE SEQUENTIAL.

       SELECT FILE-OUT
       ASSIGN TO 'OUT.DAT'
       ORGANIZATION IS LINE SEQUENTIAL.

   data division.
   FILE SECTION.
   FD IN.
   01 FILE-IN.
       05 FILE-1-IN PIC X(20).
       05 FILE-2-IN PIC 9(3).
       05 FILE-3-IN PIC 9(3).
       05 FILE-4-IN PIC 9(3).
       05 FILE-5-IN PIC 9(4).

   FD INVENT-REPORT-OUT.
   01 FILE-1-OUT PIC X(150).

   working-storage section.

   01 WS-IN.
           05 WS-1-IN PIC X(20).
           05 WS-2-IN PIC 9(3).
           05 WS-3-IN PIC 9(3).
           05 WS-4-IN PIC 9(3).
           05 WS-5-IN PIC 9(4).

   *TOTAL OF 78 BYTES
   01 WS-1-LINE-OUT.
           05 FILLER PIC X(2) VALUE SPACE.
           05 WS-1-OUT PIC X(20).
           05 FILLER PIC X(2) VALUE SPACE.
           05 WS-2-OUT PIC 9(3).
           05 FILLER PIC X(6) VALUE SPACE.
           05 WS-3-OUT PIC 9(3).
           05 FILLER PIC X(7) VALUE SPACE.
           05 WS-4-OUT PIC 9(3).
           05 FILLER PIC X(7) VALUE SPACE.
           05 WS-5-OUT PIC 9(4).
           05 FILLER PIC X(8) VALUE SPACE.
           05 WS-6-OUT PIC 9(4).
           05 FILLER PIC X(3) VALUE SPACE.
           05 WS-7-OUT PIC 9(6).
           05 FILLER PIC X VALUE X'0d'.

   01 WS-TOTAL-LINE-OUT.
           05 FILLER PIC X(16) VALUE "  TOTAL VALUE   ".
           05 WS-TOTAL-OUT PIC 9(10).
           05 FILLER PIC X VALUE X'0d'.

   *TOTAL OF 78 LINES
   01 WS-HEADER-LINE-OUT.
           05 FILLER PIC X(2) VALUE SPACE.
           05 FILLER PIC X(22) VALUE "DATA".
           05 FILLER PIC X(9) VALUE "DATA".
           05 FILLER PIC X(10) VALUE "DATA".
           05 FILLER PIC X(10) VALUE "DATA".
           05 FILLER PIC X(12) VALUE "DATA".
           05 FILLER PIC X(7) VALUE "DATA".
           05 FILLER PIC X(6) VALUE "DATA".
           05 FILLER PIC X VALUE X'0d'.

   01 WS-SEPERATOR-LINE-OUT.
           05 FILLER PIC X(2) VALUE SPACE.
           05 FILLER PIC X(20) VALUE " / / / / / / / / / /".
           05 FILLER PIC X(20) VALUE " / / / / / / / / / /".
           05 FILLER PIC X(20) VALUE " / / / / / / / / / /".
           05 FILLER PIC X(16) VALUE " / / / / / / / /".
           05 FILLER PIC X VALUE X'0d'.

   01 WS-EMPTY-LINE-OUT.
           05 FILLER PIC X(78) VALUE SPACES.
           05 FILLER PIC X VALUE X'0d'.

   77 WS-COUNT-READ PIC 9(3) VALUE 0.
   77 WS-COUNT-WRITE PIC 9(3) VALUE 0.
   77 WS-EOF PIC 9(1) VALUE 0.
   77 WS-MODULUS-RESULT PIC 9(1) VALUE 0.

   procedure division.

   100-MAIN-PROCEDURE.
       OPEN OUTPUT FILE-OUT.
       OPEN INPUT FILE-IN.
       PERFORM 310-WRITE-EMPTY-LINE.
       PERFORM 310-WRITE-EMPTY-LINE.
       MOVE WS-HEADER-LINE-OUT TO FILE-LINE-OUT.
       WRITE FILE-LINE-OUT.
       PERFORM 310-WRITE-EMPTY-LINE.
           PERFORM UNTIL WS-EOF = 1
               ADD 1 TO WS-COUNT-READ
               READ INVENT-FILE-IN INTO WS-IN
               AT END MOVE 1 TO WS-EOF
               NOT AT END PERFORM 200-CALC-WRITE-RECORD
               END-READ
           END-PERFORM.
           PERFORM 310-WRITE-EMPTY-LINE
       MOVE WS-TOTAL-LINE-OUT TO FILE-LINE-OUT.
       WRITE FILE-LINE-OUT.
       CLOSE INVENT-FILE-IN.
       CLOSE INVENT-REPORT-OUT.
   STOP RUN.

   200-CALC-WRITE-RECORD.

  *DO SOME MATH HERE

  *MOVE ALL UNCHANGED VALUES

   MOVE WS-1-LINE-OUT TO
   FILE-LINE-OUT.
   WRITE FILE-LINE-OUT.

   ADD 1 TO WS-COUNT-WRITE.

   COMPUTE WS-MODULUS-RESULT = FUNCTION MOD (WS-COUNT-WRITE, 8).


   IF WS-MODULUS-RESULT = 0
   MOVE WS-EMPTY-LINE-OUT TO FILE-LINE-OUT
       PERFORM 300-WRITE-LINE-OUT
       MOVE WS-SEPERATOR-LINE-OUT TO FILE-LINE-OUT
       PERFORM 300-WRITE-LINE-OUT
       PERFORM 300-WRITE-LINE-OUT
       PERFORM 300-WRITE-LINE-OUT
       PERFORM 300-WRITE-LINE-OUT
       MOVE WS-EMPTY-LINE-OUT TO FILE-LINE-OUT
       PERFORM 300-WRITE-LINE-OUT.

   300-WRITE-LINE-OUT.
       WRITE FILE-LINE-OUT.

   310-WRITE-EMPTY-LINE.
       MOVE WS-EMPTY-LINE-OUT TO FILE-LINE-OUT
       PERFORM 300-WRITE-LINE-OUT.

   end program PROGRAM.
```

Comment: Which compiler are you using, and which OS?

Comment: And can you show an example of the output problem, please? You should get fixed-length lines of 150 bytes followed by the record-delimiter. You are writing records to a file, not writing a report, so why would you expect any "carriage returns"? Look at the ADVANCING on WRITE if you want a report.